# Program based on pipe in Linux

Tags: linux, pipe

Write a program for this------>>>>>>

- One program will open a pipe, write a number to pipe.
- Other program will open the same pipe, will read the number and print them.
- Close both the pipes.

how can i write a program based on this any one knows it then please help me...!!!!

Comment: Can you provide more details? It's a little unclear what you're asking.

Comment: In shell: `echo 1 | cat` ... now, that's probably not what you want. Could you please clarify which part you're having a problem with, and which language you're working in?

Comment: how to write a program basically that i am asking about??

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
echo <number you want to use> (or output from program) | <program you want to pipe into>
```

For instance:

```
echo 5 | more
```

which will simply display:

```
5
```

The "|" is your pipe; it redirects output from the left to the right connecting their **standard streams**, which usually does not include stderr.

Hope that helps.

Comment: also note that you could use <program name> | <program name2> as long as the output from the left works as the input to the right, otherwise you will get an error from the right program.

Comment: how to write a whole piece of code that is my question in this case??

Comment: @Tanmay Hans's answer is perfectly correct, it is a whole piece of code that answers your question the way you asked it. It's probably not what your homework assignment intended, but that's merely because you omitted part of the assignment (probably a part where you were supposed to use a particular programming language). More than that, you've missed the whole point of homework assignments, which is for you to learn something rather than mindlessly copy-paste.

Answer (score 1):

A pipe is probably the simplest IPC solution under Linux; so talking about a pipe i like talking about a specific interprocess communication solution.

The IPC lives in the kernel space and it's managed by the kernel itself, works in 1 direction and only between a caller and a callee, it's unidirectional.

for more you should just read a good article about the pipes and the IPC under Linux, you will found a gozillion of articles [on the internet](http://www.google.com/#q=linux+pipe+ipc), for a short example you can go [here](http://hzqtc.github.io/2012/07/linux-ipc-with-pipes.html).

Comment: theory,i know very well but got stuck in how can i print the number on the screen??