# Interprocess communication using pipe in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ipc, pipe

I have written my code for writing a number to pipe in linux. it is as under,but it is showing errors,can anyone help me on this.

Basically the problem statement for the program is as below:- 
One program will open a pipe, write a number to pipe.
   - Other program will open the same pipe, will read the number and print them.
   - Close both the pipes

```
int main()
{

int number;




FILE *fout;

fout = popen("  ","w");



pclose(fout);

return 0;

}
```

Now my question is what command should i give in the popen command option (as shown blank above) so as i can proceed further and write a number to pipe.

Comment: Do you have two different programs, or the same program forking a process and communicating by pipes?

Comment: Question very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/18087047/841108 !

Answer (score 1):

First, create a named pipe using the mknod command. `mknod pipe p`. Then read and write using functions as if they are files. A node can be created using code also, using the `mknod` function. Look for error code `EEXIST`. More information here. http://linux.die.net/man/2/mknod

Comment: I don't think the exercise is about named pipes i.e. FIFO but about `pipe(2)`

Comment: I guess `pipe` is used where the parent forks a child, and both of them access the pipe, at both parent and child, one end of pipe is closed, depending on the requirements. I got confused with the term `program` instead of `process`, thought it was two different executable and so suggested named pipes. `One program will open a pipe, write a number to pipe. - Other program will open the same pipe, will read the number and print them`

Answer (score 1):

You don't understand well how IPC and pipes work; please read a good book: [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) has several chapters on these issues.

<sup>We don't have hours to explain difficult concepts covered by such good books. Take several hours to read them!</sup>

The library function [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) runs a command. Very probably, you don't have a `p` command on your system. I guess `fp` is NULL and `errno` is set.

`popen` is using [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html), [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [dup2(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) and `/bin/sh -c` etc