# Program based on pipe for interprocess communication

Tags: c, ipc, pipe

Does any one know how to write a number to pipe for that first of all i have to open the pipe, and then write suitable number to it.

Also,after writing also i have to read the number and print it.

I have tried to open the pipe with 'popen' command but i am uncertain what to give as the 1st argument to popen i.e:-

```
       popen(const char *command, const char *type)
```

i want to ask what command should i give here if i want to write a number to pipe..??

Comment: Multiple duplicates (same user): [Interprocess communication using pipe in Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159051/interprocess-communication-using-pipe-in-linux) and [Program based on pipe in Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087047/program-based-on-pipe-in-linux)

Comment: The must be another process at the other end of the pipe to read it.  You can't just write data into a pipe and leave it there.  The `const char *command` is the command at the other end of the pipe, probably a program which reads from stdin.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `fd=open(FIFO_NAME,O_RDONLY);` for reading fifo file.

```
mkfifo(FIFO_NAME,S_IFIFO|S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO);
    fd=open(FIFO_NAME,O_WRONLY);
```

fifo is also called pipe.Here mkfifo create a fifo file and the write into a file.

**Note:- that to read or write into fifo there should be a reader and writer process, Else it would be blocking one of the process.**

if you don't want to write a process for reading the use cat command and writing process to see the fifo file content.